# How can Malware Bytes scan "memory objects" in Windows?

Tags: windows, antimalware

I recently installed Malware Bytes onto a Windows PC.

As part of its scan phase it reports that it is "scanning memory objects".

I thought that Windows isolated memory address space making it impossible for one program to peer into the memory of another, or the OS itself.

What could it be scanning in this phase?

Comment: Did you run it as Admin?

Comment: No, does this make a difference?

Comment: "Memory Objects: Memory which has been allocated by operating system processes, drivers, and other applications." source: https://support.malwarebytes.com/docs/DOC-1282

Since I am not running a Windows machine I am unable to check this myself but a somewhat logical explanation could be that Malware Bytes has one or more services running with the system account?

Comment: @Remotec the OS can peer into other memory spaces, and whatever gives the OS access can be given to other processes (like AV)

Comment: Sounds like the answer!